# GoPro looping settings

Tags: video, gopro, setup

I'm using my GoPro Hero3 White as a dashcam.
Setting it to overwrite files, I encountered 2 strange things:

1. 5min settings give me 1min files, and 20min settings give 5min files.
2. The counter stops at 05:00 / 20:00 even though it goes on filming.

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening and how can I change it?

Thanks, Ronen.

Answer (score 0):

This is as it is described in the manual. These modes are continuously filming, but only saving the last 5min or 20min. This is done by splitting the part up in serveral files, and the oldest one will be overwritten. To your second question: What do you mean by 'counter'?

Comment: I assume that by `counter` OP means the numbers on the front LCD display of the GoPro. The numbers usually shows how long the camera has been filming, but on this looping setting, it shows the maximum time because it is continuously overwriting the oldest footage. So for example after 23:00 minutes of filming, the counter would show 20:00, as this is the amount of footage available from the camera.